# JQuery Autocomplete with PDO Statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am having a hard time by finding this error. I spent around 10 hours searching and testing but google couldn't provide me anything. So you guys are my really last hope.
I have a simple html textfield:

```
 <input type="text" value="" id="keyword" name="zip" placeholder="Please enter ZIP code" required>
```

and here is my Javascript code(the JQuery files are linked correctly, don't worry):

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 2;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
            var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
            if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {
                $.get( "autocomplete", { keyword: keyword } )
                    .done(function( data ) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

When I type in the textfield the value "sw" I get following result in the console:

```
["Swaziland\r","Sweden\r","Switzerland\r"]
```

Which should be correctly. Here's my first question. Are the "\r" normal?
And my second and more important question is: How do I add the query function autocomplete? My goal would be like the following example: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Please help me, I tested around for so long and I'm unable to find the solution. And I think its a little stupid error. 
Here all the files:

autocomplete.php

```
if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    die();
}
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$data = SQL::searchForKeyword($keyword);
echo json_encode($data);
```

searchForKeyword function:

```
static function searchForKeyword($keyword) {
    $stmt = self::getInstance()->_conn->prepare("SELECT NameCountry as countries FROM `country` WHERE NameCountry LIKE ? ORDER BY countries");
    $keyword = $keyword . '%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();
    $results = array();
    if ($isQueryOk) {
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with jQuery ui documentation, is to find the right page.
What you need is the [Remote jsonp datasource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example.

I lost a lot of time on the [remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) example (Wich I have not even been able to run), because I was affraid by the "p"...

So [**here is my version**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40118887/), a little enhanced, of an example to dynamically load the autocomplete dropdown.
I hope it will help lot of people.

The funny thing is that I **didn't use `jsonp`** like jQuery documentation suggests.
It creates a strange unclear error in console:

`Error: jQuery112409377035747123055_1476875409950 was not called(…)`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="https://www.bessetteweb.com/cube-fallback/images/sept.gif">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
                background: white url("ajax-loader.gif") right center no-repeat;
            }
            .ui-widget{
                width:500px;
            }
            .ui-front{
                width:10em;
                background-color:#bebebe;
            }
            #log{
                height: 200px;
                width: 500px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            #noResult{
                display:none;
                color:red;
                padding-left:1em;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( function() {
                function log( message ){
                    $( "<div>" ).text( message ).appendTo( "#log" );
                    $("#UScities").blur();
                }

                $( "#UScities" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "search.php",
                            data: {keyword:request.term},
                            dataType: 'json',               // DON'T use jsonp !
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){

                                console.log(data);

                                // Even on success, it may have no results...
                                if(typeof(data[0])!="undefined"){

                                    // Remove the no result error in case it's displayed
                                    $("#noResult").css("display","none");

                                    // For fun, count it!
                                    var count = 0;
                                    while (data[count]) {
                                        console.log(data[count]);
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    count = "NO";
                                    // Display the no result error
                                    $("#noResult").css("display","inline");
                                }

                                console.log(count+" RESULTS");

                                // Pass the data to the dropdown!
                                response(data);
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                console.log(errorThrown);
                            }
                        });

                    },
                    minLength: 4,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        log( ui.item.value );
                    }
                });

                // Show results on input focus
                $("#UScities").on("focus",function(){
                    $("#ui-id-1").css("display","block");
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="UScities">USA cities: </label>
            <input type="text" id="UScities"><span id="noResult">No Result</span><br>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
            <div id="log" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've added the result count in console (which could be used to trigger something) and a "NO RESULT" message to user, because it is possible to get no result on a keyword search.

Now, what is lacking terribly in the jQuery documentation, is how to produce a json output.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    // Do nothing if no keyword!
    die();
}

// Database connection infos (PDO).
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=[Database Name];host=localhost';
$user = '[Database User]';
$password = '[UserPassword]';

try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connexion failed : ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Getting the keyword and add % to get data that begins with it.
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'] . '%';

// If you want the keyword to be "contained" in the data, use (uncomment it):
//$keyword = '%' . $_GET['keyword'] . '%';

// Query.
$query = "SELECT city FROM SO_USAzipcodes WHERE city LIKE ? GROUP BY city limit 30";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword);

// Executing.
$stmt->execute();

// If SQL error...
if (!$stmt) {
   echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
   print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
   die();
}

// Fetching.
$data = array();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

// This is sending the json to autocomplete.
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

If you have a syntax error in this file...
Or if there is an error due to DB connection or a SQL syntax error...

You will get something like this in console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)
```

And nothing happens in the main page, but the rotating `.gif` that keeps on turning. By the way, I just discovered this [loading gif generator](http://www.ajaxload.info/) that worth seeing. ;)

Comment: I will try that out and let you know, however already a big thank you!!

Comment: So I tried it out. Here again my problem. I always get the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)" error. This is because I have to link the search.php file. In my case its called autocomplete.php. But as l'm working with the MVC principle, so I have to link it with php. Like that: url: "<? ROOT_DIR.'views/autocomplete.php';?>" But this doesnt seem to work =( Any suggestions?

Comment: This error you have is because your autocomplete.php is trowing an error instead of a json. Access it directly to fully see the error (using the full path + keyword like `https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40118887/search.php?keyword=mass`) or check you `error.log` file in the directory where the file is... to debug, echo your vars...

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much, you were right!